# Facebook Graph Search Post Combine FQL queries

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am wondering there is a method that is combine fql and graph search. I really need this method. Because I search public posts and then I take user information so I must send two request to facebook api. I believe i can take post and user information using one request. Maybe I must combine fql and graph search api. Does anyone have any idea how can I do it?

For posts:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=simple&access_token={1}
```

For users:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids={0}&access_token={1}
```